# Excel formula to copy a cell to another

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a formula to copy the info from one cell to another depending on the value in a third cell.

Example:

```
E..........G............K...........M
20........30...........12.........???? 
12........22..........20..........????
```

In the 1st row, M should be 22-because K(12) exists in the E column in the 2nd row where G is 22.

In the 2nd row, M should be 30-because K(20) exists in the E column in the 1st row where G is 30.

By the way, E is not the first column so VLOOKUP does not work.

How can I do it? Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are right about not using *VLOOKUP()*, however *INDEX()/MATCH()* will work just fine:

In **M1** enter:

```
=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(K1,E:E,0))
```

and copy downwards

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but it says the formula is wrong. It shouldn't matter that 2 of these columns (G and E) are from another sheet in the same excel document.Right?

Comment: @E.K  It will work only if the schema is like my picture.

Comment: So, if G and E are some columns in another sheet in the same document?

Comment: @E.K then you must modify the formula.

Comment: I modified it accordingly but still gives error     =INDEX('Gov'!A:A,MATCH(C4,'Gov'!I:I,0))